# How to fulfill the space with 8 uiviews?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a slight problem to resolve and looking for any cocoapod or framework which let me solve my problem:

[image]

Requirements:

- all images should fill circle as much as possible.
- space between them and between edge of the circle should be acceptable and just nice;)
- position of any image within circle should be randomly generated.
- every image should have randomly changed size.
- rotation of any image should be randomly generated
- every image should preserve its ratio.
- every image should not be greater than A value, and should not be smaller than B value (A and B always is related and compared to the longest side of rectangle)

Comment: Sounds like a question for math.stackexchange.com